# Can I Disable the Download All feature on a shared Google Photos album?

Tags: google-photos

If I share a Google Photos album, other people who view it see a *Download All* button at the top of the page, as shown in the screenshot below. You should be able to see it yourself if you visit [this album](https://goo.gl/photos/pv4Swa3MSTi3ktP49).

Is there any way to prevent that button from being shown? I've looked in my Google+ settings under *Photos and Videos*, and the option *Allow viewers to download my photos and video* is already unchecked.

[image]

Comment: +1 I find this quite curious. Is the "Allow viewers to download my photos" feature just for people within your circles for posts you may make?

Comment: @Raystafarian With the pretty messy confluence of Google Photos, Google Drive, Google+ and PicasaWeb, I suspect not even Google know the answer to that question!

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot do this on Google Photos.

--Update--
Not a chance with Google now, they are shutting down Picasa at 1st May.

<strike>This option is **only available on Picasa web album**. Google Drive does have an option to block the download link in the "advance" section of the share settings, and it will create a new Picasa album with uploaded photos automatically. However, you cannot edit such album on Picasa and will get a "500 Internal Server error" when you try. So you may want to upload your photos to Picasa directly.</strike>

Comment: Unfortunately, Picasa Web Albums have been announced to be shut down.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that after I found my Picasa link  was forwarded to Google Photo and did some search...